# Is it possible to fetch the app analytics data from firebase using java spring boot api

Tags: java, spring, firebase, maven, google-analytics

Is it possible to fetch the app analytics data from firebase using java libraries. My project is under the spark plan of firebase which is of no cost plan.I need to fetch the analytics data like number of active users,number of downloads of the application from firebase.I will be using java spring boot maven application to get it. Is it possible to fetch the values from firebase in this plan?

Comment: The answer to "is it possible" questions is almost always yes. See [ask] for some tips on asking a more specific question.

Comment: See the question I linked, and from the API mentioned there this seems a good palce to start: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries#java_1